# Filter Select by id in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table with registered antennas and I want to relate them to an access control, each antenna can only have an access control but the access controls can have many antennas, I want to filter a select with only the antennas that are not installed in a control access but I do not know how to do it. This is what I have so far:

```
module Admin::AntennaReaderRfidsHelper
  def antennas_for_select

    antenas_rfid = AntennaReaderRfid.all
    antenas_installed = AntennaInstalled.all

    antenas_rfid.map do | antena |
      antenas_installed.map do | instalada |

        if antena.id != instalada.antenna_reader_rfid_id
          puts antena.id
        else
          puts antena.id
        end

      end
    end
  end
end

<%= f.select(:antenna_reader_rfid_id, antennas_for_select, { include_blank: '' }, { class: 'form-control' }) %>
```

Comment: Whats the class name for **registered antennas** and **access control**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `name` is column_name in `AntennaReaderRfid`

In controller#action

```
@options_antennas_for_select =  AntennaReaderRfid.where
                                                .not("id IN (?)", AntennaInstalled.pluck(:antenna_reader_rfid_id))
                                                .pluck(:name, :id)
```

In view

```
<%= f.select(:antenna_reader_rfid_id, @options_antennas_for_select,  {prompt: "Select"}, {class: 'form-control', required: true}) %>
```

Comment: @AlexCs Glad to know that, can you upvote answer, :)